# Testing nested functions with jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I'm stuck in a thought loop whether (and how) I should test nested functions for a translation service that we wrote.

The problem is as followed:
Each mongoDB document can have nested or populated document references which can could have something like 'name' or 'title' or something similar. These properties have an object containing translations such as English, Dutch, ect.

Our service layer have 'translate' functions that call the translation utility with an object and the desired language, for example
`const libraryTranslated = libraryService.translate(library, dutch)`

However, the `libraryService.translate` has a nested translate function for the `category` service to chain them all together.

```
public static async translate(library: ILibraryDocument, language: Language): Promise<ILibraryDocument> {
    // does stuff
    library.category = categoryService.translate(library.category, language)

}
```

So my thought is "I want to test whether a library document is correctly translated, including its nested documents" but I already know that I'm going to have countless cases with nested documents containing nested documents containing (ect) because our platform has become quite complex.

What is the best approach to test this? (and should I even test it this way, or should I just stick with the individual translate functions and be done with it?)

Comment: If you're testing to ensure the service functions are called you can spy on or mock them to ensure they've been called with the appropriate parameters--but that only needs to be done once--the remaining tests can focus on the results of `translate` regardless of how `translate` is implemented.

Comment: hmm yes that would make sense, because I'm checking if library.category is not undefined, and then it goes to the category service, which is covered in its own tests. I think this is the solution! Thanks!